# Difference between various Radiant Barrier types

Tags: insulation, attic

Can someone explain me the difference between radiant barrier types and which one is the best option?

I am seeing products like foil, Double Insulated Metalized Mylar Double Foil Bubble Wrap.

I do not understand the difference between them if there is any.

Comment: @Ecnerwal cool do you want me to give you +1? reported.

Comment: No, I want you to clarify the question so that it is answerable. It still appears to be the case that you are listing only two items - one foil, which is, well, foil, and the other appearing as perhaps being two or maybe three products run together or perhaps one product with a really long name. So: *Double Insulated Metalized Mylar Double Foil Bubble Wrap* **or** *Double Insulated Metalized Mylar, Double Foil Bubble Wrap* **or** *Double Insulated Metalized Mylar, Double Foil, Bubble Wrap* ?

Answer (score 2):

Radiant barriers are great in theory, but in practice they usually fall short.  The primary reasons are:
1.  Once they get dusty, they don't work.
2.  People press them right up to the surface they are trying to insulate (and air cavity between the radiant barrier and the next closest surface is necessary - at least 3/4").

Adding a radiant barrier to an existing form of insulation can't hurt, but as a stand alone product I usually find their effectiveness lessens substantially over time.  So to answer your question:  Unless you have a specific need where radiant barriers can perform, I wouldn't spend a lot of effort or cost seeking one out.